# Losing data while reading serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

While reading the answer of a microcontroller from the serial port to an array (`byte[] _LOGdata`), I'm always missing some sent bytes when finished.

The number of received bytes can be up to `1500000` and I'm using a timeout to detect the end of the stream.

Here's a part of the code. Any ideas where the problem happens?

```
ComPort.PortName = ActualPort;
ComPort.BaudRate = 250000;
ComPort.Parity = Parity.None;
ComPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
ComPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
ComPort.DataBits = 8;
ComPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
ComPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
ComPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
ComPort. ReadBufferSize = 8192;   // enlarging buffer size helps
ComPort.Open();

ComPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
ComPort.DiscardInBuffer();

DateTime timeout_counter = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(500);

byte[] _LOGdata = new byte[100...1500000];  // value varying

Array.Clear(_LOGdata, 0, _LOGdata.Length);  

int BufferedBytes = 0;
int byteCounter = 0;

while (true)
{
    if (ComPort.BytesToRead > 0)  // read bytes, when they come in
    {
        BufferedBytes = ComPort.BytesToRead;
        ComPort.Read(_LOGdata, byteCounter, BufferedBytes);  // write already recieved bytes to the array
        byteCounter += BufferedBytes;
        timeout_counter = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(1000);
    }

    if ( DateTime.Now > timeout_counter) break;
}
```

Comment: If you don't use the SerialPort.ErrorReceived event then you'll never see an error.  Just bad data.  A high baudrate with no handshaking makes buffer overruns likely.

Comment: I'm actually checking the number of bytes received for error handling.
To solve the problem I just enlarged the serialPort.ReadBufferSize and also added a 10ms delay in the microcontroller software after sending every 5000 bytes.
Now it works fine.

Comment: That doesn't eliminate overrun errors, it merely reduces the odds you get one.  Still a problem when, say, a large gen#2 garbage collection runs, a storm of page faults hit or the machine is bogged down by other processes.  You need to implement RTS/CTS handshaking in the microcontroller.  Or at least use the ErrorReceived event so you can tell somebody about the mishap.